# How to debug vsprintf() "Too few arguments" error in my log files?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, localisation, log, debugging

I keep seeing the following report in my `system.log` file:

```
2015-10-20T12:34:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => vsprintf(): Too few arguments
    [file] => app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Translate.php
    [line] => 416
)
```

I suspect it comes from the extension I wrote but I'm not sure.
what's the best way to debug this? how do I know where it comes from? looking at the code at `Translate.php` doesn't help much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the other answer already stated, this is probably caused by too few arguments in a call to a translator method.

You have more `%d` or `%s` placeholders in the translations string then arguments passed additional to the string.

You should create a copy of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` and add a temporary debug call there in the `translate()` method just above the `vsprintf($translated, $args)` call.

You could add something like this:

```
if (substr_count($translated, '%') != count($args)) {
    Mage::log(
        __METHOD__ . '() possible argument count mismatch! '
        . 'Backtrace: ' . mageDebugBacktrace(true, false, true)
    );
}
```

Logs will be written to `var/log/system.log` when logging is enabled (and the log file is still the default `system.log`).

It's a simple check, so it would also appear when you have a translate string containing an escaped percentage character, like `"You get 5%% discount!"`

**You should not edit the core file directly, but if you do then please do not forget to revert this core file to it's original state afterwards! Or else [Ben Marks will be mad](https://iglo.tech/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/hey-did-you-just-edit-the-core.png)!**

Comment: @Ness did you find where it was coming from?

Comment: nope, but it was enough to find out it comes from another extension and not mine, so I don't really care :) your answer was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: You should NOT edit `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` instead create a copy of Translate.php in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` and edit it there.

Comment: @Black it's temporary. Most of the times in Magento 1 projects I would have the core code also in VCS. So it will be really easy to see core changes and revert them with a simple `git checkout -- app/code/core/`. Of course it's best to develop a habit of copying to `app/code/local/`. You'd see those files in your 'untracked' list when doing `git status` and you could just delete them again. You cannot easily see what has changed with `git diff` though, because the `app/code/local/` copy will just be a complete new file to Git.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without seeing the offending code, but I think you may have a translation call with insufficient number of parameters, something like:

```
echo $this->__('There are %d things in %s places', $arg);
```

Check your code for that.

Comment: yeah I know, but my point is I have no idea what the source of this error and this is what I'm asking - how do I find the source or any relevant information about it? thanks

Comment: Search your custom module for an unescaped `%`. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, here is the best answer based on the issue I encountered in Magento 1.9.3.8 after installing it fresh.
Replace the `vsprint` line in the `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Translate.php:416` with:

```
try {
    $result = vsprintf($translated, $args);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $translated;
    exit;
}
```

This will print the issue string on the screen. For me it was this one: `Please input a valid CSS-length. For example 100px or 77pt or 20em or .5ex or 50%.`
Then you can search the code for the string and  escape it if it's your code. If not, then you found a bug in someone else's code. Submit a bug report to them so they can fix it. In this case, this is in `Mage_Core`, so it's a Magento bug that was overlooked when releasing.

Comment: You should not edit the core file directly, create a copy in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` and do whatever you like there! Otherwise you will loose upgrade compatibility. And also you are writing `Exception $e` but you never use `$e`.

I tried your solution and nothing appears at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Magento Core. This bug can be fixed by escaping percent signs in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/jstranslator.xml` **(search for '%' and replace with '%%')**.

Then it's possible to remove the **@** from **@vsprintf** in line 416 of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Translate.php` to read: 
**$result = vsprintf($translated, $args);**

The **@** sign there only hides the error in most places unless you use a **set_error_handler** function. Properly escaping the % in the xml will fix the error itself.

To test, you can add the **validate-css-length** class to a form field and type in an improper css unit of measurement and see that there is only one %.

I don't know how to suggest this as a patch, but it's been like this since at least 2015. You shouldn't edit the core files directly, but you can copy them from core to local and make the changes there.